# WMI CommandLineTemplate Variables Cutting Off

Tags: windows, powershell, events, wmi

I've been working on a solution to monitor and respond to certain windows services stopping, and I could really use a few hundred extra sets of eyes on this. I'm setting up the WMI subscription in Powershell and the subscription seems to do it's job, but I'm not getting the expected output using the CommandLineTemplate. I'm trying to push the service name, current state, and previous state to a powershell script or executable (same PS script but compiled) but I only get part of the first variable before it cuts off. I've tried formatting the commandlinetemplate multiple different ways, escaping the variables with single/double/escaped quotes, and tried re-ordering the variables, but it always seems to be part of the first and nothing else gets passed. For testing I'm just trying to grab the variables and write them to a log before I move on to the more fun stuff.

Subscription Code:

```
$instanceFilter = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = "WQL"
$instanceFilter.Query = "select * from __instanceModificationEvent within 5 where targetInstance isa 'win32_Service' AND targetInstance.Name LIKE 'ServiceNamex.%'"
$instanceFilter.Name = "ServiceFilter"
$instanceFilter.EventNamespace = 'root\cimv2'
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()
$newFilter = $result.Path

#Creating a new event consumer
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:CommandLineEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$instanceConsumer.Name = 'ServiceConsumer'
$instanceConsumer.CommandLineTemplate = "C:\Tools\ServiceMonitor.exe `"%TargetInstance.Name%`" `"%TargetInstance.State%`" `"%PreviousInstance.State%`""
$instanceConsumer.ExecutablePath = "C:\Tools\ServiceMonitor.exe"
$result = $instanceConsumer.Put()
$newConsumer = $result.Path

#Bind filter and consumer
$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\.\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()
$instanceBinding.Filter = $newFilter
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $newConsumer
$result = $instanceBinding.Put()
$newBinding = $result.Path
```

Target Code (PS1/EXE):

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Position=0)][string]$serviceName = "Error",
    [parameter(Position=1)][string]$currentState = "Error",
    [parameter(Position=2)][string]$previousState = "Error"
)
Add-Content -path "C:\temp\service.log" -value "$(Get-Date) - The state of $serviceName on $env:Computername has changed from $previousState to $currentState."
If ($currentState -eq "Stopped")
    {
        Add-Content -path "C:\temp\service.log" -value "$(Get-Date) - Attempting to restart $serviceName."
        Start-Service -DisplayName $serviceName
    }
```

Example Output for ServiceNamex.Funct.QA.12 stopping and starting:

```
10/30/2019 03:52:11 - The state of ServiceNamex.Funct.QA. has changed to Error.
10/30/2019 03:52:16 - The state of ServiceNamex.Funct.QA. has changed to Error.
```

Comment: How do you call the PowerShell script?

Comment: @HAL9256 In the example above I'm using the compiled version using 'ServiceMonitor.exe <serviceName> <currentStatus> <previousStatus>' but I've also tried calling it as a PS1 script using the following (and fifty varieties of escaping).


$instanceConsumer.CommandLineTemplate = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Tools\ServiceMonitor.ps1 `"%TargetInstance.DisplayName%`" `"%TargetInstance.State%`" `"%PreviousInstance.State%`""

Answer (score 0):

Chris, It looks like the issue lies in the variables that you're getting from the first script. I'm not sure where you're getting those variables from. The ServiceMonitor.exe application isn't a PS script and I don't see where the subscription calls out to ServiceMonitor.ps1

Just copying your PS lines into a ServiceMonitor.ps1 file, I was able to run the following command and get the subsequent log information.

```
.\ServiceMonitor.ps1 TestService Running Stopped
```

> 11/01/2019 11:01:24 - The state of TestService on 7D25PX1 has changed from Stopped to Running.
>   11/01/2019 11:13:11 - The state of TestService on 7D25PX1 has changed from Stopped to Running.
>   11/01/2019 11:13:44 - The state of TestService on 7D25PX1 has changed from Stopped to Running.

Hopefully that helps to at least point you in the right direction. Feel free to respond with more information and I'll be happy to update the post.

Comment: @TheldesOfMark Thanks for taking a look at this, you're right that in the first script I'm calling ServiceMonitor.exe but this is simply a compiled version of ServiceMonitor.ps1, which I did to try and rule out a problem with calling the full powershell.exe path to call the PS1 script. Whether I'm using the .ps1 or .exe version, I get the right output when I run it from powershell using hard values like in your example. The problem only occurs when I enable the WMI subscription (first code block) and the script or exe are called by WMI. It seems as though the output from WMI is being cut off.

Comment: Character limits.... so in my example, if the service is named 'ServiceNamex.Funct.QA.12' and it goes from started to stopped, I will only get 'ServiceNamex.Funct.QA.' for the service name and nothing for the other two variables (current and previous state). If I switch the variables on both scripts around to put service name last, the first state will be truncated as something like 'Stopp' and then nothing else for the other two.

Comment: Have you tried it with the ServoceMonitor.ps1 -args `"%arg1%`", etc? I can't do much testing here, my admin privileges haven't come through yet, so my PS modules are really limited, and I don't have access to the WMI modules.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help either way! I just gave it a shot, simplified the ps1 to just set variables based on args 1, 2, and 3 and I get the same result. The last two digits of the service name are cut off, and the state values are blank.

Comment: I was really hoping someone else would chime in by now. If you're still working on this, I would suggest trying to capture the output of $instanceConsumer.CommandLineTemplate before each action to see when the output gets filtered or gets the wrong values. I'm also not sure how much of this is actually running as batch and how much as pwsh, so you might look at escaping your strings differently. For batch scripts '/' is the standard escape character. https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php